# How to create a document in Word with two columns without column break at the bottom of the page?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm creating a bilingual document in MS Word and would like to have two columns for the two different languages.
The issue is that at the bottom of the pages the document is continuing on the second column automatically.

The ideal would be to have the original text in the first column and the translation in the second one with the paragraphs on the same level for both text.

I'm stuck now, do you have any idea how to do it?

As a workaround I'm doing with a two-column table but it's not an elegant solution.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Word uses "newspaper style" columns which behave the way you describe, continuing on the right once you reach the bottom on the left. What you're looking for is "parallel style" columns. Unfortunately the only easy way to mimic the parallel style is what you've already found, using tables. Using auto-fit tables and hiding the borders can make them look a little nicer but they're the only real option.

Answer (score -1):

I guess @Steve Brennan would have already found a solution. But you can achieve what was intended by applying column break at end of first column. By doing so can have same level paras in both columns.